# more verbose linker output to show symbols

Tags: visual-studio

When adding the /VERBOSE:lib flag it is supposed to show "The displayed information includes the library search process and lists each library and object name (with full path), *the symbol being resolved from the library, and a list of objects that reference the symbol*."

I can't seem to get VS2012 do this. It just shows the .lib's searched, not the symbol being resolved

```
1>  Searching libraries
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x86\shcore.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x86\msxml6.lib:
1>      Searching C:\src\openssl\lib\libeay32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\src\openssl\lib\ssleay32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x86\kernel32.lib:
```

What would be causing the full output not to show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `/VERBOSE` along with `/VERBOSE:LIB` generates much more detailed output.